# Check PFTableViewCell based off PFRelation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have a `PRelation` between a Category and Items I am looking to make a `PFQueryTableViewController` to be used to add Items to the Category. The `PFQueryTableViewController`lists all of the Items and the user selects the items to put in the Category. All I am trying to figure out is how to determine if the Item is in the Category and set the `PFTableViewCell` accessoryType to `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`

Current Code:

```
- (PFTableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

    static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    BOOL itemInCategory = ?; //This is where I am determining the hierarchy

    PFTableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.text = [sendingObject valueForKey:@"Title"];
    cell.accessoryType = itemInCategory ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    return cell;

}
```

**Edit**

I also need some help removing the Item from the Category:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    BOOL itemInCategory = ?;

    if (itemInCategory) {

        //Remove Item?

    } else {
        PFRelation * relation = [sendingObject relationforKey:@"Items"];
        [relation addObject:[self.objects objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
        [self save];
    }

}
```

Should be pretty simple

Cheers

Comment: Can you specify the type of "Item" that you are adding to "relation"?. If the item is a custom object, you can override isEqual: method and write a condition where two objects would be equal, for eg. objectId, uniqueId etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come across a similar situation. I made a container for keeping selected indexPaths.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray*selectedIndexPaths;
```

Initialize the selection container

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.selectedIndexPaths = [@[] mutableCopy];
}
```

Check if a particular indexPath is stored in selection container array

```
- (PFTableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

    static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    BOOL itemInCategory = [self.selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath];

    PFTableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.text = [sendingObject valueForKey:@"Title"];
    cell.accessoryType = itemInCategory ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    return cell;

}
```

If an indexPath is stored in selection array remove item from relation else add it and reload tableView.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

       BOOL itemInCategory = [self.selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath];
       PFRelation * relation = [sendingObject relationforKey:@"Items"];

       if (itemInCategory) {

           //Remove the item from selectedIndex container and also relation
           [self.selectedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
           [relation removeObject:self.objects[indexPath.row]];

       } 
       else {

           [self.selectedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
           [relation addObject:self.objects[indexPath.row]];
           [self save];
       }

       [tableView reloadData];

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This technique below keeps the track of the items which were previously selected and which were unselected, based on the section and row number.
Since a tableview is established based on a list that already persist and we have with us...
At the time of action to be performed **"`checkMarkSectionsDictionary`"** will provide us the list of selected items.
    [checkMarkSectionsDictionary ALLKEYS]// returns us the key of the sections
And against each section we will have selected rows.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *checkMarkSectionsDictionary = nil; //need to be defined at class level


if ([checkMarkSectionsDictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.section]]) {
    NSDictionary * checkMarkRowDictionary = [checkMarkSectionsDictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.section]];
    if ([checkMarkRowDictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]]) {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];            
    }
}
else{
        // category was not found in selected items
}



//DID SELECT


//CHECK / UNCHECK
if ([checkMarkSectionsDictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.section]]) {
    //SECTION EXISTS
    NSMutableDictionary * checkMarkRowDictionary = [checkMarkSectionsDictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.section]];
    if ([checkMarkRowDictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]]) {
        [checkMarkRowDictionary removeObjectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
    }
    else{
        [checkMarkRowDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
    }
    if (checkMarkSectionsDictionary.count == 0) {
        [checkMarkSectionsDictionary removeObjectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.section]];
    }
}

else{

    //SECTION DOESNOT EXIST CREATE IT AND SET THE SELECTED ROW
    NSMutableDictionary *checkMarkRowDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
    [checkMarkSectionsDictionary setObject:checkMarkRowDictionary forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.section]];

}

[_tableView reloadData];
```